# Is Apache Knox Gateway compatible with Cloudera 4.5?

Tags: apache, security, hadoop, cloudera, knox-amazon-s3-client

I'm currently working on a future project with an Hadoop cluster. I need to find informations about security of the cluster.

I found the API Apache Knox Gateway which seems to be what we need. We work with Cloudera 4.5 for now. In the future, we will upgrade to Cloudera 5.

My problem is that Knox seems to not be compatible with Cloudera 4.5 (http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH-Version-and-Packaging-Information/cdhvd_topic_3.html).

```
WebHDFS                   2.4.0 
WebHCat/Templeton         0.13.0    0.12.0  
Ozzie                     4.0.0
HBase/Stargate            0.98.0
Hive (via WebHCat)        0.13.0
Hive (via JDBC)           0.13.0
```

(http://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-4-0/knox-0-4-0.html#Quick+Start)

According to the website, this is the only versions tested. Does anybody have an experience with this API and Cloudera 4.5 ?

If it can't work, is there any solution to have a cluster secure ?

Comment: Any news about CDH (now 5.3) and Apache Knox compatibility?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, Apache Knox is a way to provide security at the perimeter of your cluster for REST API access. It is not a replacement for kerberos security within the Hadoop cluster when that is truly warranted. It continues to complement the kerberos enabled cluster as well by extending the reach of REST APIs into the enterprise. It also provides some additional identity solution integrations for end user access.

If what you want is real Hadoop security then you need to look to the Hadoop kerberos deployment options.

Now, as for knox/CDH compatibility...

The supported versions of service components for Knox 0.4.0 do not map well to the CDH 4.5 release unfortunately. It looks as though even the 0.3.0 releases are newer than CDH 4.5.

CDH 5.0 seems to line up better though HBase is still lagging behind. from what I see [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/dam/cloudera/Resources/PDF/Datasheet/Cloudera_Datasheet_CDH_Projects_and_Specifications.pdf) - I can only assume that is accurate.

My suggestion would be to try Apache Knox against CDH 5 and engage the knox community with any difficulties - there may be work arounds that we can help with. Depending on your REST needs - there may be enough alignment to get what you need.