# what is cloudera's alternative to apache knox?

Tags: apache, api, thrift, cloudera, stargate

I saw [this question on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246530/is-apache-knox-gateway-compatible-with-cloudera-4-5) but there haven't been updates, so I am asking this again: any news if Knox is compatible with CDH (5.3) or, if not, what should we use in CDH to expose a secure data feed through a REST API?

Thrift?

Stargate?

Is there an alternative to do this without HBase?

And mostly is there somewhere where I can have more complete info about this? I cannot believe this is not a common problem and yet I find it hard to find info.

Any contribution is welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Apache Knox with CDH 5.3.
It isn't exactly clear which APIs you are looking to expose from your post.

Stargate is the REST server for HBase.
If you are trying to expose Stargate through a firewall for a secured cluster then Knox would allow you to open a port to Knox and access Stargate and other services through that single endpoint.

I'm not sure what you are asking about Thrift.

Hope this is helpful.